# Change default xml namespace(xmlns) to a custom one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In a XAML file we usually use the default setting
`xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"`

How can I define a custom xmlns instead of the default one. Such as
`xmlns="http://www.mypage.com"`

I don't mean add to a new xmlns, but replace the default one.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: Have a reading of this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/knom/2007/11/02/wpf-tired-of-xmlnsclr-namespace/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you're not using elements and attributes from the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation` namespace, then it's not really XAML any more, just some random XML that happens to use element/attribute names that are similar to XAML ones.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what your problem is... if you want to use the default namespace somehow different than suggested, just prefix the (normally) default namespace with a name:

```
<def:Window x:Class="WpfTests_2.MainWindow"
        xmlns:def="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns="clr-namespace:WpfTests_2"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <def:Window.Resources>
        <CustomBox x:Key="myLocalCustomBox"/>
    </def:Window.Resources>

    <def:Grid x:Name="grid1">
    </def:Grid>
</def:Window>
```

In this example, I make the project local namespace `WpfTests_2` the default and name the (normal) default namespace as `def`.

For a typical WPF application, *this is a bad idea because you will use many controls and you need to prefix your namespace name every time*. But it is certainly possible.

If you don't use anything from the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation` namespace (no `Window`, no `UserControl`, no [whatever control]), you can remove/replace it without redefining it with a prefix.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is possible, by second part doc below:

`For almost all of the examples given in the WPF sections of the SDK, the default XAML namespace is mapped to the WPF namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation.`

Since `almost all` , That is there exists few example are not using this url, so it's possible.

*[Docs Of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml#what-is-a-xaml-namespace)*

> **The WPF and XAML Namespace Declarations**
>
> Within the namespace declarations in the root tag of many XAML files, you will see that there are typically two XML namespace declarations. The first declaration maps the overall WPF client / framework XAML namespace as the default:
>
> *xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"*
>
> The second declaration maps a separate XAML namespace, mapping it (typically) to the x: prefix.
>
> *xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"*
>
> **Mapping to Custom Classes and Assemblies**
> ...

*[Another Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-overview-wpf#xaml-root-elements-and-xaml-namespaces):*

> The root element also contains the attributes `xmlns` and `xmlns:x`. These attributes indicate to a XAML processor which XAML namespaces contain the type definitions for backing types that the markup will reference as elements.
>
> The xmlns attribute specifically indicates the default XAML namespace. **Within the default XAML namespace, object elements in the markup can be specified without a prefix.** For most WPF application scenarios, and **for almost all of the examples given in the WPF sections of the SDK, the default XAML namespace is mapped to the WPF namespace** http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation.
>
> The `xmlns:x` attribute indicates an additional XAML namespace, which maps the XAML language namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml.
>
> This usage of `xmlns` to define a scope for usage and mapping of a namescope is consistent with the XML 1.0 specification. XAML namescopes are different from XML namescopes only in that a XAML namescope also implies something about how the namescope's elements are backed by types when it comes to type resolution and parsing the XAML.
>
> Note that the `xmlns` attributes are only strictly necessary on the root element of each XAML file. `xmlns` definitions will apply to all descendant elements of the root element (this behavior is again consistent with the XML 1.0 specification for `xmlns`.) `xmlns` attributes are also permitted on other elements underneath the root, and would apply to any descendant elements of the defining element. However, frequent definition or redefinition of XAML namespaces can result in a XAML markup style that is difficult to read.
>
> The WPF implementation of its XAML processor includes an infrastructure that has awareness of the WPF core assemblies. **The WPF core assemblies are known to contain the types that support the WPF mappings to the default XAML namespace.** This is enabled through configuration that is part of your project build file and the WPF build and project systems. **Therefore, declaring the default XAML namespace as the default `xmlns` is all that is necessary in order to reference XAML elements that come from WPF assemblies.**

Comment: The namespace definitely doesn't have to be the default. Elements an attributes have to be used from the _correct_ namespace, but whether you do that by using a default namespace declaration or by using a prefix doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I see you updated your answer. It's really better now.